# Json MVC3 Object value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am sending json list from my controller:

```
 public ActionResult LoadTree()
        {

            List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>() {
                new ListItem() { Text = "Keyvan Nayyeri" },
                new ListItem() { Text = "Simone Chiaretta" },
                new ListItem() { Text = "Scott Guthrie" },
                new ListItem() { Text = "Scott Hanselman" },
                new ListItem() { Text = "Phil Haack" },
                new ListItem() { Text = "Rob Conery" }
            };

            return new JsonResult { Data = list };
        }
```

Trying to get the list in my view using:

```
var text =
            $.ajax({
                url: '/CourseCases/LoadTree',
                dataType: 'json',
                 data: {     },
                cache: false,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
            alert(text);
```

I just get [object object].  How I can get the actual value of the object?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: well you could use console.log(data) and look what the object contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to set the `JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in the `JsonResult`.

```
    public ActionResult LoadTree()
    {
      List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>() {
                new ListItem() { Text = "Keyvan Nayyeri" },
                new ListItem() { Text = "Simone Chiaretta" },
                new ListItem() { Text = "Scott Guthrie" },
                new ListItem() { Text = "Scott Hanselman" },
                new ListItem() { Text = "Phil Haack" },
                new ListItem() { Text = "Rob Conery" }
            };

      return new JsonResult { Data = list, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/LoadTree',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
          alert(data.length); // 6
          // do whatever with the data
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mark for providing a complete answer, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`function $.ajax()` **does not return value from server**, so `var text = $.ajax()` will not work. You need to look at success handler instead

```
success: function (data) {
    // data is the result of your ajax request
}
```

I strongly recommend you to read more at [jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) A function to be
>   called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three
>   arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to
>   the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Comment: Doing `success: function (data)` is perfectly fine, only use the other two arguments if you need?

Answer (score 0):

in success function you have to parse json to get actual data e.g.

```
var jsObject = JSON.parse(data);
```

and then access each item like jsObject.List[0].Text etc

Comment: This is not needed - specifying dataType: 'json' in request makes jQuery parse result and give you javascript object in data.

Comment: it will give you the object and then you can get info from it, as you have placed your list in Data so you can access by iterating through list jsObject.Data.List[0].Text

Answer (score 0):

Simple problem here. In your controller, you're actually assigning the list to a variable named `Data` **inside** the response data collection. Just because your success function takes a `data` parameter doesn't mean that the `Data` value you set in your controller *automagically* will become the `data` variable.

As your `Data` list is **inside** the `data` object: you need to do:

```
data.Data
```

inside your success function. Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data.Data.length);
}
```